# Use MapboxSearchBox on an input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mapbox, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

Banging my head against the desk for a few hours on this one. Basically I want to use the [MapboxSearchBox](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-search-js/api/web/search/#mapboxsearchbox.event:retrieve) on an input field within my app.

The field itself calls uses a stimulus controller to initalize the MapboxSearchBox JS like so:

```
  export default class extends Controller {

  connect() {
    const input = document.getElementById('default-search');

    if (input !== undefined) {
      new MapboxSearchBox({
        accessToken: this.mapboxToken,
        country: "gb",
        types: "neighborhood,postcode,street",
        input: input
      });
    }
  }
```

The input field is like so:

```
<%= text_field_tag :location, params[:q], id: "default-search", placeholder: "Type a location", required: true, data: { controller: "mapbox" } %>
```

The JS is being called however the search box isn't appearing, yet when I use something like this in my code it is appearing:

```
<mapbox-search-box
access-token="<your access token here>"
proximity="0,0"
>
</mapbox-search-box>
```

Could someone point me in the right direction of where I'm going wrong?